# Problem installing OTB for QGIS 2.8.15 in ubuntu

Tags: qgis, otb-applications

I'm experiencing a problem in installing OTB for QGIS 2.8.15 in my ubuntu 16.04.

I'm following the instructions in
https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/QGIS_access_to_OTB_applications

but when I do "make" I obtain this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Comment: Why don't you use the otb package from the ubuntugis unstable ppa?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know. May you give me some other info thanx?

Comment: The otb wiki seems a bit outdated. The download page of QGIS and https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/ tell you how to add the ubuntugis ppa. It comes with a current GDAL version, so you need the QGIS repo with ubuntugis support as well. You need to remove and purge QGIS before if you have used the debian repo, and maybe the self-compiled otb stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much. At the end I installed the standalone version of OTB with the Monteverdi interface. I find it very clear and intuitive. Maybe I will give up and I will stay use it. Thank you very much